# Unable to use Enter to next line

Tags: front-end, keyboard

My question is almost similar to [Gappy Hilmore](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226263/75304) but slightly different.

In my case, I can use `Shift + ENTER` to run the code as usual.
Note: it's `ENTER` for me as I'm using Dell laptop, Mathematica 12.2 on Windows10

The problem is, I'm not able to use `ENTER` just for the sake of going to the next line on the same cell.

This is my current situation, everything has to be a long code without a nice separate line in between (if not I have to merged the cells manually)

[image]

...and once I press enter, it just goes to the next input line

[image]

I did uninstall Mathematica and reinstalled it, but the problem stays. I try to manually corrected `KeyEventTranslations.tr` as mentioned by [Ilian Gachevski here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/118999) but still not working.

This is not coding technicality, but it's annoying.
I didn't have this problem on macOS or Windows7.

Any tips and tricks anyone? Cheers!

Comment: Which “enter” key are you using? Is it possible that your enter key is being interpreted as the enter on the number pad? In that case, it is treated as shift+enter.

Comment: @CATrevillian this laptop has only one `Enter` key . I'm still new with this laptop, do you think it has to do with the computer?

Comment: From what you've shown, it looks like pressing ``Enter`` key runs the ``Divide Cell`` command, which usually has a keyboard shortcut [``Shift+Ctrl+D``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLAfB.png). Can you confirm that the action of ``Enter`` key is indeed the same as using ``Divide Cell`` from the menu? Can you check which shortcut is bound to the ``Divide Cell`` command in the menu?

Comment: @Domen, you're right. The `Enter` key works just like the `Divide cell`, and checking from the Cell menu, the `Divide Cell` also has the same shortcut `Shift + Ctrl + D`. Do you have the solution from here? If you do, post it, I'll be happy to accept your answer

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have an immediate solution, but I have some other troubleshooting steps that might help :-) Do you use default English keyboard layout (in Windows) or a local one? Does it work if you switch to some other keyboard layout? Does the behaviour change if you turn on (or turn off) the ``NumLock``?

Comment: @Domen Yes, I use the default English keyboard, and the `enter` is still behaving like before even with `Numlock` 's on

Comment: It seems that ```FrontEnd`ReturnCreatesNewCell``` has been set to `True`.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq I've finally found the solution! After weeks. Thanks. Do you want to post a complete answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematica 12.1 is treating all my cells as raw texts by default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235105/mathematica-12-1-is-treating-all-my-cells-as-raw-texts-by-default)

Comment: @nightcape We have already had several answers of this question on this site. I flagged this question as a duplicate after your confirmation.

Comment: The decriptions of these questions are different, but they have the same answer: [228879](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228879/pressing-the-enter-key-in-the-python-external-evaluation-cell-becomes-run-in) [235105](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235105/mathematica-12-1-is-treating-all-my-cells-as-raw-texts-by-default)

Comment: @rnotlnglgq That's right, different problems, but solved with the same solution. I just run this ``SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FrontEnd`ReturnCreatesNewCell -> False]`` on the notebook, and things get back to the original. Thanks for your help!